# Delete child table data in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three table like, `user`, `article`, `saved_article`,

User

```
has_many : saved_articles, dependent: :destroy
```

Article

```
has_many : saved_articles, dependent: :destroy
```

SavedArticle

```
 id | article_id | user_id | #-> Table

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :article
```

`SavedArticle` creating success fully but problem is when I try to delete,

My deleting action:

```
def remove
  current_user.saved_articles.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to home_path
end
```

Remove form:

```
<%= form_for :remove, url: home_remove_path(id: current_user.saved_articles.id), method: :delete, remote: true  do |f| %>
  <%= f.button 'Remove'.html_safe, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Deleting..."}, :class => 'btn btn-default btn-delete' %>
<% end %>
```

Showing based on upper code :

> undefined method `id' for #SavedArticle::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000016fddd90

When I debug like below:

`<%= debug current_user.saved_articles %>` then showing all attribute inside the table.

my question is how can I delete my specific attribute  from `saved_articles` table.

Thanks

Comment: current_user.saved_articles this will give you a collection proxy like array of articles ... you can not take id of the collection so you  got the error

Comment: then how to access id?

Comment: The simple ideal way `home_remove_path(2)` send the id to the controller method here 2 is the id. Please do not haroded(like 2) just get the id from the view itself when form is called

Answer (score 0):

Form is not required to delete an saved article, Just use the following code in your views,

```
<%= link_to 'Remove'.html_safe, "#{url_path_for_delete}?id=#{saved_article.id}", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?', remote: true } %>
```

Pass in the saved_article's id in the above link and replace the url with the delete method url for the controller method.

Make sure the controller routes are of method 'delete' in routes.rb

Comment: I need delete one, just where do I click

Comment: I guess you dont want to delete all the saved articles, rather require the view to delete one saved article. right?
In that case don't need to change your controller code, Just put in ,

<%= link_to 'Remove'.html_safe, "#{url_path_for_delete}?id=#{saved_article.id}", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?', remote: true } %>

Comment: Thanks, but  now showing `undefined local variable or method saved_article`

Comment: Do you have the id of the saved_article you want to delete? please pass that in the link I have specified. Change the 'saved_article.id' to the saved_article's id you want to delete.

Comment: Problem is that when use `current_user.saved_articles` then showing all data `where user_id = current_user.id` but not accessing to `current_user.saved_jobs.id`, when use this showing error

Comment: current_user.saved_articles is a collection. It will list all the articles under a user. If you want to choose an id, the use this
<% current_user.saved_articles.each do |saved_article|%>
<%= link_to 'Remove'.html_safe, "#{url_path_for_delete}?id=#{saved_article.id}", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?', remote: true } %>
<%end%>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

in views

```
<% current_user.saved_articles.pluck(:id).each do |aid| %>
<%= form_for :remove, url: home_remove_path(aid), method: :delete, remote: true  do |f| %>
  <%= f.button 'Remove'.html_safe, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Deleting..."}, :class => 'btn btn-default btn-delete' %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

And in controller you get the id one by one on each request.

if you want to delete all save articles by one click 
then

```
<%= form_for :remove, url: home_remove_path, method: :delete, remote: true  do |f| %>
  <%= f.button 'Remove'.html_safe, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Deleting..."}, :class => 'btn btn-default btn-delete' %>
<% end %>
```

and in controller

```
def remove
  current_user.saved_articles.destroy_all
  redirect_to home_path
end
```

Comment: Now problem is if saved 2 articles then every option showing 2 remove buttons

Comment: please check my update post to destroy all articles by one click button remove

Answer (score 0):

In your `saved_article` controller, add `before_action :authenticate_user!` (if you are using devise). This will ensure that in whatever you are doing, the current user has to be available. Then put this in your `destroy` action

`def destroy
  @saved_article = SavedArticle.find(params[:id])
  @saved_article.destroy
  redirect_to ..., notice: ...
end`

Then add a link in your view to delete the `saved_article`
`<%= link_to 'Delete', @saved_article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }`

Don't forget to have your routes set